# Basic auth returns 403 in postman but works fine in browser

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, basic-authentication

I've defined securityConfig as following:

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery(\\some code\\)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(\\some code\\)
                .getUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
    }
```

When I am entering the credentials in the form in my browser it works fine,

[image: form in my browser]

but when I try to send the request in postman using basic auth form [image: postman]

I get 403 error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by [CSRF protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html).

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#when-to-use-csrf-protection):

> Our recommendation is to use CSRF protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by normal users. If you are only creating a service that is used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.

CSRF protection can be disabled as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and()
            .csrf().csrf().disable()
}
```